# nullpointer exception in android logcat interpretation

Tags: android

i`m encountering this part error in my app:

i have this logcat:

```
03-09 00:25:49.213: D/AndroidRuntime(431): Shutting down VM
03-09 00:25:49.213: W/dalvikvm(431): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at me.mojica.caloriewatch.Search$1.onItemClick(Search.java:231)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 00:25:51.363: I/Process(431): Sending signal. PID: 431 SIG: 9
03-09 00:25:53.853: D/dalvikvm(441): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 58K, 52% free 2603K/5379K, external 2000K/2137K, paused 105ms
```

where the only part i can understand is this:

```
03-09 00:25:49.253: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at me.mojica.caloriewatch.Search$1.onItemClick(Search.java:231)
```

in my class

```
       String data1 = food.getText().toString();
       String data2 = calories.getText().toString();
       mySQLiteAdapter1.insert1(data1, data2); <---------------- line number 231
       updateList();
```

and in my adapter i put it this way

```
public long insert(String foodname, int i){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_FOODNAME, foodname);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CALORIES, i);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);    

}
```

i don`t know if the wrong part is at my class i declared it in string then in my adapter has 1 int and 1 string

updated: this is the code of my class:

```
package me.mojica.caloriewatch;

import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Search extends Activity {

private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
private FoodlogAdapter mySQLiteAdapter1;

int arlene=0;
int textlength=0;

ListView listContent1, transact;
EditText search, food, calories;
Button FSearch;
TextView result;


SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter, cursorAdap;
Cursor cursor, Tcursor;
private String[] listview_array;
private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.search);
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


  listContent1  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lFoodlist1);
  //transact  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.transact);
  search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eFsearch);
  food= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  calories= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);  
  FSearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bFsearch);
  result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);


  /*
   *  Create/Open a SQLite database
   *  and fill with dummy content
   *  and close it
   */
  mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
  mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Adobong Baboy (1 bowl)", 339);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Adobong Kangkong ( 1 bowl)", 84);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Adobong Manok (1 bowl) ", 624);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Adobong Pusit (1 bowl)", 121);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Arroz Caldo (1 bowl)", 500);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Chicken Afritada (1 bowl)", 323);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Chicken Asado (1 bowl)", 205);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Chicken Empanada (1 bowl)", 150);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Chicken Tinola (1 bowl)", 267);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Dinuguan (1 bowl)", 255);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Fried Bangus (1 pc)", 162);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Ginataang Kalabasa (1 bowl)", 225);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Ginataang Langka (1 bowl)", 167);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Ginataang Pinakbet (1 bowl)", 155);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Igado (1 bowl)", 297);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Kare Kare (1 bowl)", 129);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Laing (1 bowl)", 202);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Lechon Kawali (1 bowl)", 245);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pakbet (1 bowl)", 233);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Paksiw na Isda (1 bowl)", 73);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Paksiw na Pata (1 bowl)", 342);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pinakbet (1 bowl)", 110);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Afritada (1 bowl)", 402);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Asado (1 bowl)", 533);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Barbaque on Stick (1 stick)", 111);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Embutido (1 bowl)", 350);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Mechado (1 bowl)", 157);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Nilaga (1 bowl)", 181);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Pochero (1 bowl)", 798);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pork Sinigang (1 bowl)", 290);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Relyenong Bangus (1 bowl)", 390);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Salmon Sinigang (1 bowl)", 190);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Sisig (1 bowl)", 293);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tilapia (1 pc)", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tinolang Manok (1 bowl)", 843);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tortang Talong (1 pc)", 291);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Balut (1 egg)", 188);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Beefsteak (1 bowl)", 210);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Bibingka", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Biko (1 slice)", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Buko Pie (1 slice)", 145);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Cassava Cake (1 slice)", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Chicsilog (1 meal)", 284);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Coorned Beef (1 meal)", 267);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Danggit (1 pc)",98);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Ice Cream", 157);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Embotido", 187);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Ensaymada", 410);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Espasol", 50);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Fishball (1 pc)", 9);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Fruit Salad (1 bowl)", 211);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Galapong (1 slice)", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Ginataan (1 bowl)", 167);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Halaya", 70);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Halo halo (1 cup)", 80);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Hotdog (1 pc)", 183);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Kutsinta", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Leche Flan", 228);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Lomi", 222);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Longganisa (1 pc)", 170);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Lumpiang Shanghai (1 pc)", 169);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Palabok", 305);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Palitaw", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pancit", 416);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pansit Palabok", 305);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pastillas (1 pc)", 76);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Porksilog (1 meal)", 555);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pulvoron (1 pc)", 40);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Puto (1 pc)", 112);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Puto Bumbong (1 pc)", 50);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Puto Pao (1 bun)", 120);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Qwek qwek (1 pc)", 14);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Saging na Saba", 122);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Sapin sapin (1 slice)", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Scrambled Egg", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Sinangag (1 cup)", 300);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Siopao", 240);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Suman (1 pc )", 31);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Taho (1 cup)", 180);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tapsilog (1 meal)", 364);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tikoy (1 slice)", 100);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tuyo (1 pc)", 57);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Yema (1 pc)", 20);

  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Apple", 80);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Apricots", 17);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Avocado", 30);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Banana", 105);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Blueberries", 82);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Cherry", 4);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Coconut", 159);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Eggplant", 132);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Grape Fruit", 62);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Guava", 61);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Kiwi Fruit", 25);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Lemon", 24);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Limes", 20);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Lychee", 4);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Mango", 107);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Melon", 188);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Orange", 62);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Peach", 38);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pineapple (1 slice)", 42);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Pomelo (per section)", 72);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Rambutan", 7);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Raspberries", 82);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Strawberry", 8);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Tomato", 15);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Watermelon (per slice)", 46);



  mySQLiteAdapter.close();

  /*
   *  Open the same SQLite database
   *  and read all it's content.
   */
  mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

  Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
  startManagingCursor(cursor);

  String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_FOODNAME,SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CALORIES};
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2};

  SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
   new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

  listContent1.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
  listContent1.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener); 
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
  }

  private ListView.OnItemClickListener listContentOnItemClickListener = new         ListView.OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
       Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

      String item_content1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_FOODNAME));
      String item_content2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CALORIES));
      arlene = arlene + Integer.parseInt(item_content2);
      String item = String.valueOf(" Food Name: " + item_content1 ) + "\n" +
              " Calories: " +  item_content2;

       Toast.makeText(Search.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      

       food.setText(item_content1);
       calories.setText(String.valueOf(arlene));

       /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Foodlog.class);
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("SQLITEDATA1", food.getText().toString()); 
       bundle.putString("SQLITEDATA2", calories.getText().toString()); 
       myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivity(myIntent); */

       String data1 = food.getText().toString();
       String data2 = calories.getText().toString();
       mySQLiteAdapter1.insert1(data1, data2);
       updateList();

       //SavePreferences("food", food.getText().toString());
       SavePreferences("calories", calories.getText().toString());
       LoadPreferences();
  }}
  ;

protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
}

private void updateList() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Tcursor.requery();
}


protected void LoadPreferences() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("food", "");
String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("calories", "");


//food.setText(strSavedMem1);
calories.setText(strSavedMem2); 
}

  }
```

as for my adapter:

```
package me.mojica.caloriewatch;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class SQLiteAdapter extends Search{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row);
}

public static final String APP_NAME = "AdvancedSearch";
public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "Food_DB";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "Food_Table";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FOODNAME = "FoodName";
public static final String KEY_CALORIES = "Calories";

//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
        "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_FOODNAME + " text not null, " + 
                KEY_CALORIES + " integer);";



private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String foodname, int i){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_FOODNAME, foodname);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CALORIES, i);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);    

}

public long insert1(String foodname, int i){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_FOODNAME, foodname);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CALORIES, i);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);    

}


public int deleteAll(){
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public Cursor queueAll(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_FOODNAME, KEY_CALORIES};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}

 public void update_byID(int id, String v1, String v2){
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(KEY_FOODNAME, v1);
      values.put(KEY_CALORIES, v2);
      sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
     }


public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

        }

public String[] qall(){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_FOODNAME, KEY_CALORIES};
    String[] listview_array = null;
    try{
         cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            listview_array=new String[cursor.getCount()];

            int foodName = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FOODNAME );
            int keyColories = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CALORIES );
            int l=0;
            boolean moveToNext = cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
            listview_array[l]=cursor.getString(foodName) + "                              " +
                    cursor.getString(keyColories);
               l++;
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(APP_NAME, "An error occurred while searching for "+search+": "+e.toString(), e);
    }finally{
        if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return listview_array;

}

public void open()
{
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void delete_byID(int item_id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID, null);
}


}
```

Comment: `mySQLiteAdapter1` is null. That's the best anyone here is going to be able to tell you unless you provide the rest of your code.

Comment: You have `mySQLiteAdapter1.insert1(String, String)` but then the insert method is defined as `insert(String, int)`. I'm just confused by this...

Comment: when i change data2 to int i got multiple errors

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException occurs because mySQLiteAdapter1 is null, not any of the values you are passing in.

From the code you've posted, it does not look like mySQLiteAdapter1 is initialized anywhere. I would expect it to be initialized as part of your onCreate().